# scrolling a div with youtube video under another div

Tags: html, css, youtube

I have my HTML as below

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="d1" 
  style="height:100px;width:100%;background-color:#CFE;position:fixed;z-index:1000"> 
</div>

<div id="d2" style="padding-top:110px;z-index:-1000;background-color:#CCE;height:1000px;">
<iframe width="420" height="315" 
   src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XZxo7IznQnk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Top div (d1) is fixed. while scrolling bottom div(d2) goes behind top div. But youtube video
stay on top.

I want to put it behind top div. Is there a way??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved it.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="d1" 
  style="height:100px;width:100%;background-color:#CFE;position:fixed;z-index:1000"> 
</div>

<div id="d2" style="padding-top:110px;z-index:-1000;background-color:#CCE;height:1000px;">
<iframe width="420" height="315" 
   src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XZxo7IznQnk?wmode=transparent" 
     frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note ?wmode=transparent"  in src of iframe

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that the iframe is holding the flash youtube video on top. It has to do with the z-index of a Flash object.

I've used this solution before with success...

http://manisheriar.com/blog/flash_objects_and_z_index

- Put your Flash content into a wrapper div called flash
- Add  to your object tag
- Add wmode="transparent" into the embed tag
- Use CSS to set the position and z-index for your div (don't set negative z-index values as it will hide your Flash)

Use this css:

```
#flash {
    position: relative; /*or absolute*/
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Edit: you would have to remove the Iframe. Wich would of bin a good idea in the first place, since iframes suck :p

Comment: I have tried but youtube iframe get disapear after adding wmode="transparent"

Answer (score 1):

That's because ActiveX objects tend to sit on top of ALL html elements. You'll have to have to add a "windowless" mode to your

```
<object>
    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
</object>
```

Comment: or you can add wmode="Opaque"> to your <iframe /> tag like Adi's link suggests :)

Comment: I have removed iframe and used object tag with <param name="wmode" value="window" />. But it has no effect

Answer (score 0):

What I tried when I came across similar situation:

```
 #bridgeDIV
{
position:relative;
}

#riverDIV
{
position:fixed;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Imagine river flowing under the bridge.